# example of opening a new text file in a certain place on the computer in python

Tags: python-3.x

All the examples I find are in the current directory or are not examples at all.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to open a file in Python if it is not in the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an absolute path.

```
f = open('C:/file.txt', 'w')
f.read()
```

If you actually wanted to change the working directory, use [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)

Comment: Thanks.  I think I figured it out.  The slashes were going the wrong way.  Os.chdir- sounds interesting.